# I can't to call action method in the controller from view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to call the "Delete Person" method from the "Home" controller on the link provided by the "Index" view, but get the error: "could not find this resource": HTTP 404, URL: /Home/DeletePerson/1. I tried @Html.ActionLink, but it doesn't work either. Where is my mistake?
The project has .NET Framework 4.7.2, Entity Framework 6.2.0, MVC 5.
This project has HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    public ViewResult Index()
    {            
        ...
        return View("Index");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DelelePerson(int id)
    {
       ...           
        return View(person);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeletePersonConfirmed(int id)
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

My Index.cshtml includes

```
<td><p><a href="/Home/DeletePerson/@b.Id">Del</a></p></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `Html.ActionLink` to create the correct link They are aware of your specific routing configuration. Second, your link should probably look like "/Home/DeletePerson?id=@b.id", but that depends on your routing configuration which you haven't posted.

Comment: This is my RoutConfig.cs - routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: Maybe you have a relative directory configured which is why your link starting with "/" does not work. Please use the asp-* attributes to create the link. If that still doesn't work please show us the generated link from the source code viewer of your browser.

Comment: I've removed the tag helper information from my answer, it belongs to ASP.NET Core and you're still using ASP.NET MVC 5.